# return a % in C# with if statements

Tags: c#

I am working on a school project and I am trying to write a C# program that will allow the user to input total sales. I need to take the total sales and   calculate it by the profitRatio as follows:

```
totalSales                      profitRatio
0-$1,000:                           3%
$1,000.01-%5,000                    3.5%
$5,000.01-$10,000                   4%
Over 10,000                         4.5%
```

The next step would be to calculate the total sales by the % category that it matches and store that data. I will also want to display the profit ratio % used to the user along with the new profit. Will “if then” statements work to do this if written like this?

```
private decimal ReturnRatio()
{
    if (totalSales > 0 && totalSales < 1000)
    {
        profitRatio = .03M;
    }
    else if (totalSales >= 1000.01 && totalSales < 5000)
    {
        profitRatio = .035M;
    }
    else if (totalSales >= 5000.01 && totalSales <= 10000)
    {
        profitRatio = .40M;
    }
    else if (totalSales < 10000)
    {
        profitRatio = .045M;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Will “if then” statements work to do this if written like this?". Run the code and see for your self. If you aren't convinced after that then plop in a break point and run it again with debugging.

Comment: My sweet summer child :).  You are using 3 different data types in there where you should only be using one.  Make all your numbers end in M.

Comment: lookup how to use the `string.Format` function and either change the return type to a string that has the formated value with the `%` also you are aware that the current code will produce an error since you do not have a `return profitRatio` for example `var dValue = string.Format("{0:0.0%}", .03M);` in your case you would change .03M with profitRatio, in the string.Format function `var dValue = string.Format("{0:0.0%}", profitRatio);`

Answer (score 0):

In your last branch, `else if (totalSales < 10000)` you would allow in numbers that are `<= 0`>.  I think that last branch should be `else if (totalSales > 10000)`.

Well, the last branch should probably really be an else statement that handles other amounts since the user is allowed to enter amounts.  For example:

```
else if (totalSales > 10000)
{
   profitRatio = .045M;
} 
else 
{
   Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid amount.");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my type O, I also appreciate the input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If then statements will work, but if I were your teacher I would be hoping for more.  You should consider creating a Range class with a field for Min and a field for Max, then create objects to represent each category.

Place these Range objects in a collection like a List, then do a foreach loop to go through each Range object individually.

If this were code in an enterprise system, I would hunt you down unless this was the hot loop in some extreme performance stuff.

Comment: The OP has a question about `if` statements and you're criticizing for not being enterprise-worthy?  Everybody has to start somewhere - if the code _works_ I see no compelling reason to make such drastic changes at this level.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion hoodaticus, unfortunately I do not have enough knowledge on the foreach statement “we have not learned this yet” and how to use it properly so I am in the processes of looking this up. If you wouldn’t mind sharing an example of your suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it. I am not asking to solve the whole problem for me, just enough to get a good basic idea of your suggestion.

Comment: LOL @ D Stanley.  You're just upset because of the pwning you received on another question.

Comment: @JohnMarren - it's enough at this point that I've implanted in your mind the seeds of the next steps you'll need to take this to the next level :).  You'll learn it, I am sure.  Just never give up and you'll be one of the best one day.

Comment: Sounds good to me  hoodaticus, I beleive that I am going to go with   MethodMan suggestion. Thank you for your help hoodaticus and MethodMan!